# window.location.reload() is not working

Tags: angular5

I used

```
window.location.reload();
```

in my angular 5 project. when I run "ng serve" it works fine. But when build it using "ng build" and deploy in xampp server page not loading. How can I solve it?

Comment: share more code and also share console error

Comment: If you are getting 404 errors, it most likely is because you need to setup your xampp server to return the index page for resources not found on the server if you are using HTML5 style routing (non-hash based URL routing)